# Can I modify Kubernetes scale-up scale-down wait times

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I have enabled auto-scaling on my deployment. I would like to modify the default scale-up scale-down settings. Looking at the documentation scale-up will wait 3 minutes before it will scale up again. I would like to increase this wait time to 10 minutes.

Is there a way to modify this setting?

Kubernetes version 1.5 currently deployed

"Scale-up can only happen if there was no rescaling within the last 3 minutes. Scale-down will wait for 5 minutes from the last rescaling."

https://github.com/kubernetes/community/blob/master/contributors/design-proposals/horizontal-pod-autoscaler.md#autoscaling-algorithm

Comment: It is very limited in flexibility right now, so sadly: No (Also see https://kubernetes.io/docs/api-reference/v1.6/#horizontalpodautoscaler-v1-autoscaling for details)

Answer (score 0):

The version i tried is 1.7 and we can define the time to scale upto 10 mins. not sure about 1.5 version

$ kubectl autoscale deployment httpd --cpu-percent=25 --min=1 --max=10

Comment: Thanks but that scales from 1 min pod to 10 pods max. I am trying to change the time kubernetes waits to scale up again

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is still active but you can now use the flag `--horizontal-pod-autoscaler-downscale-stabilization` on the controller manager. You can find the details in the [kubernetes docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale/#support-for-cooldown-delay)